# 【Xcode】archiveしたら以下のエラーがでました。解決方法をお教え下さい

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Appleに審査依頼をする際に、Xcodeからarchiveしたら以下のエラーがでました。解決方法をお教え下さい。

「itunes store operation failed. no suitable application records were found」

[image: itunes store operation failed. no suitable application records were found]

Comment: [Xcode error when uploading to App Store: "No suitable application records were found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110757/xcode-error-when-uploading-to-app-store-no-suitable-application-records-were-f)

Answer (score 2):

このへんは参考になりませんか？

No suitable application records were found.ではまった…
http://blog.goo.ne.jp/kunibu/e/e95ca3a24eca251f8eed4c7c70b16176